# Different behavior of KClass between Kotlin-jvm and Kotlin-js

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-js

I wrote some kotlin code to show a difference of behavior between the execution on jvm and in js. How could I fix this?

This equality: booleanKClass == genericKclass
is **true for JVM**
but **false** for JS

I’m going to paste the code followed by the output generated by the console (one for jvm and one for js)
If you call test1() from a multiplatform project you will see this as I did.
I’m using kotlin_version = ‘1.2.51’

```
fun test1() {
    val values = PropertyDelegate()
    val result = Result(values)
    println("This will call the delegate getter.")
    println("result.success is not really important but: ${result.success}")
    println("This will call the delegate setter...")
    result.success = true
    println("end")
}

class Result(del: PropertyDelegate) {
    var success: Boolean by del
}

class PropertyDelegate() {
    inline operator fun <reified T> getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        val booleanKClass = Boolean::class
        val genericKclass = T::class
        println("getValue (booleanKClass == genericKclass) is ${booleanKClass == genericKclass}")
        return true as T
    }

    inline operator fun <reified T> setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        val booleanKClass = Boolean::class
        val genericKclass = T::class
        println("setValue (booleanKClass == genericKclass) is ${booleanKClass == genericKclass}")
    }
}
```

JVM output:

```
This will call the delegate getter.
getValue (booleanKClass == genericKclass) is true
result.success is true
This will call the delegate setter...
setValue (booleanKClass == genericKclass) is true
end
```

JS output:

```
This will call the delegate getter.
getValue (booleanKClass == genericKclass) is false
result.success is not really important but: true
This will call the delegate setter...
setValue (booleanKClass == genericKclass) is false
end
```

Comment: Fun. I don't see why this shouldn't work, even with limitations in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-reflection.html. In JS, `genericKclass` is shown as `class null`.

Comment: Feel free to vote related issues https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23178 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17527

Comment: JFYI: the issues are fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as expected since Kotlin 1.3.41.

Prints:

```
This will call the delegate getter.
getValue (booleanKClass == genericKclass) is true
result.success is not really important but: true
This will call the delegate setter...
setValue (booleanKClass == genericKclass) is true
end
```